# Vue-router не обновляет компонент после перехода (this.$router.push)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Делаю блок интернет-магазина, который выводит похожие товары.

Работает это следующим принципом:
В компоненте Vue на хуке created запускаю метод который делает запрос в elasticsearch и вытаскивает оттуда массив объектов c похожими продуктами.
Пример блока с товарами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема** заключается в следующем:
Когда я жму на ссылку  то URL сайта меняется, но сам контент компонента не обновляется. Но если перезагрузить страницу, то отрисовка само-собой происходит правильно. Скорее всего не происходит повторный запрос в elasticsearch.

```
data() { 
  return {
    product_ids: [1625224, 1596300, 1568229, 1568437, 1879192]
  }
}

created () {
  this.getSimilarProducts(this.product_ids)
},
methods: {
 async getSimilarProducts(product_ids) {
   const responseData = {
      entityType: 'product',
      query: elasticSearchQuery,
   }
   const response = quickSearchByQuery(responseData)
   response
      .then(result => {
        // Обработка массивов...
      })
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример после клика по ссылке товара:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте вывод дебаг информации. `title` должен меняться после изменения URL? `uniqueFormats`? Повесьте watcher на эти переменные и выводите их значения до и после изменения роута.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно делать запрос каждый раз при изменении url, то можно использовать метод watch, который будет следить за изменением url и делать запрос на каждое изменение

```
created () {
  this.getSimilarProducts(this.product_ids)
},
  watch: {
    $route() {
       this.getSimilarProducts(this.product_ids)
    },
  },
```